# Position after resizing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

It looks like jquery changes the poition of elements when I resize them.

I have a resizable (and draggable) element inside another. Resizing and dragging are constrained to a grid, and to within the parent element.

When I load the page the draggable element has top position 89.68333435058594, but as soon as I resize it horizontally, it goes to 89.

Since the grid is built around the height of the element plus a gutter, this becomes a mess, as it constrains movement: as soon as I move the element to another position further down, I can't move it back, as it won't fit anymore.

Did anyone encounter this issue? and did you find a solution?

Comment: I think browsers do not precision percentages, they instead round it up to the nearest whole number as an int or floor it which mean 4.9 would be 5 so u wont see that extra 0.6833... of space

Comment: @Val not true, http://jsfiddle.net/sJQeZ/ :: changing the width of `article` to 75% will leave a white gap between the red and blue element.

Comment: @phoenix I just checked the W3 website and it does say <numbers> which means they can have zeros, but I have had problems personally can't remember which browser, but thats news to me :) +1